# Texture Region 2D Array - Why are my sprites drawing so small?

Tags: java, libgdx

Using the `Libgdx` Framework, I'm generating an `Actor` from an `Assets.java` class and then drawing him depending on the state he is currently in. The problem i'm having is that he's coming out ridiculously small. I'm noticing that when I split the Texture into regions the `.Split()` function doesn't provide width and height parameters in comparison to a singular declaration of the texture region function here: `new TextureRegion(Texture, x, y, width, height);`

Note: I've also set the size of the world, the actor size etc they don't need to change how small he is. I'm assuming it's something to do with the sprite size or assets class. But the way i'm slicing the Texture works perfectly for the engine i've created.

**I'm wondering is there something I'm missing or something to add to define the width/height of the TextureRegions inside the**`Assets.java` **code snippet?**

All my sprites are in a 512x512 Texture with a height and width of 85px

Relevant Code:

```
rubenSprite = loadTexture("data/rubenSprite.png");
        rubenFrames = TextureRegion.split(rubenSprite, 85, 85);

        WalkF1 = rubenFrames[0][0];
        WalkF2 = rubenFrames[0][1];
        WalkF3 = rubenFrames[0][2];
        WalkF4 = rubenFrames[0][3];
        WalkF5 = rubenFrames[0][4];

... More TextureRegions
```

If more code is needed, or anything elaborated let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of actor is not size of texture inside. Actor has boundaries. When this boundaries are too low image cannot fit inside. On to the contrary, it is analogously.
You should set your actor as:

```
setWidth(width);
setHeight(height);
setBounds(left, right, width, height);
```

And make sure, that texture is also set to width and height.

btw. 
I recommend, use drawables with Actors. It is more clearer. You create skin, where you define all your moves and then you call your textures from the skin.

Comment: My draw method was overloading to a different function than I expected, it was assigning originx and y instead of width and height, i removed 2 parameters from the draw method and assigned the actors height to that method. It worked.+1 for effort and simplicity.